# How to to fetch embedded data from mongodb using query?

Tags: mongodb

I have embedded data of user in authentication token schema and i want to fetch the token on the basis of username/email.

My json is in database is :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("556573e744ae59c06a45533e"),
    "_class" : "com.samepinch.domain.user.AuthenticationToken",
    "token" : "c19f368e-8734-4a17-970e-e60e77dd955b",
    "user" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("556566ca44ae69d5428778c5"),
        "age" : 0,
        "username" : "qsiddiqui81@yahoo.com",
        "firstName" : "Qasim",
        "lastName" : "Siddiqui",
        "email" : "qsiddiqui81@yahoo.com",
        "gender" : "male",
        "createdDate" : ISODate("2015-05-27T06:40:10.871Z"),
        "updatedDate" : ISODate("2015-05-27T06:40:10.871Z")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want only token as output you should add it in projection by matching criteria.
As you want to match `username` and `email` in `user` object
 you can use following query :

```
db.collection.find({
    "user.username": "qsiddiqui81@yahoo.com",
    "user.email": "qsiddiqui81@yahoo.com"
  }, {
    "token": 1
})
```

If you want to match `username` or `email` in `user` object you can use -

```
db.collection.find({
$or: [{
        "user.username": "qsiddiqui81@yahoo.com"
       }, {
        "user.email": "qsiddiqui81@yahoo.com"
     }]
    }, {
    "token": 1
})
```

Comment: i also want to write cutome query in repository using @Query . Can you help me in this

Comment: @Qasim sure. but didn't get your question. can u update it in your question please?

Comment: Thanks for replying @vishwas .  I am using @Query("{'user.id' : ?0}")
 AuthenticationToken findByUserId(String userId); but not getting AuthenticationToken object from mongodb

Comment: @Qasim. Still it is pretty unclear about what you are saying. Which driver/language you are using? Do you want to convert this query using any other mongo driver. Please add more description. If you want to match with object id, use db.collection.find({"_id":ObjectId("add mongoId here")},{"token": 1})

Comment: I am using spring with mongodb and i have built mongo repository in which i    have write my custom query mentioned above.

Comment: [This](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.2.x/reference/html/mongo.repositories.html) will helpful to you to create repository.

Comment: @vishvas see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30482482/how-to-write-custome-query-in-mongodb-repository

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you can do this:

```
collection.find_one({"user.username": "qsiddiqui81@yahoo.com",
                     "user.email":"qsiddiqui81@yahoo.com"},
                    {"token": 1, "_id": 0})
{"token": "c19f368e-8734-4a17-970e-e60e77dd955b"}
```

I am used to query it through pymongo (the python interface) so you may need to change the query a little bit.

What you need to known is the dot notation to query subdocuments